# click events on svg groups

Tags: jquery, svg

I am fairly new to SVG and wanted to ask for some help. What I have is a map and I have grouped elements using  within the SVG code. Each group has an ID.

I have the following function that once you hover over a group a div with the rel attribute the same as the svg group id is then shown on the right of the screen.

This works but what I need if for it to work when you click on the svg group not when you hover. How can I trigger a click event with SVG Groups?

```
$('svg g').hover(function() {
    $(".map-data").hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".location-information[rel=" + id + "]").show();
},function(){
    $(".location-information").hide();
    $(".map-data").show();  
});
```

Any help of advice would be great here. Thank you kind people.

Comment: You want to replace `hover` with `click`? So that at first click it does what "hover in" does now, and at second - what "hover out" does?

Comment: Is jquery really necessary? I made a few interactive apps with SVG, but haven't use jquery...

Comment: Yes I tried replacing .hover with .click and even tried a very simple click function. Neither work on the svg but did for another div once tested.

Alex - It's because I am loading in content from another area and hiding other content on the svg click. (or trying to). How would you aproach this? Have you done click events on SVG groups before in another way?

Comment: I found a solution that uses jquery with sizzle to allow me to load in the SVG and target the id's of the group. Anyone who wants the code just ask :)

My issue is now this has stopped any other jquery working on my site. e,g, cycle2 plugin. Any ideas how to overcome this?

If I delete the jquery and just call in the jquery with sizzle nothing else works.